# Catch 404 on xhr.js, when Axios GET is called and express server sends .json()

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, axios, http-status-code-404

On my client Vue.js application the console gives me an 404 error, when calling my express API, with an invalid API token.

E.g. calling `http://localhost:8081/confirmation/invalidToken`
gives, me

```
xhr.js?b50d:172 GET http://localhost:8081/confirmation/a 404 (Not Found)
```

Of course it is possible for someone to use that invalid link, so I want to handle these errors instead of printing the error on the console.

If on my express server side, I send the response, like this:

```
return res.status(404);
```

Then the console error disappears.
Edit: However this only seems to be the case, because the request is not finished and it's waiting. After a while, the console logs a "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error.

It's only appearing if I send the response like this:

```
return res.status(404).send({
  message: 'No valid link!',
  error,
});
```

or this:

```
return res.status(404).send({
  message: 'No valid link!',
  error,
});
```

Catching on client side is not working for this problem.

```
public async sendConfirmation(token: string): Promise<any> {
  try {
    return axios.get(this.baseURL + '/confirmation/' + token);
  } catch (error) {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log(error.response);
  }
}



sendConfirmation(this.token)
 .then((res) => {
   // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
   console.log(res);
   if (res.status === 404) {
     throw new Error("404");
   }
   this.data = res.data;
   if (res.status === 201) {
     this. messagetype = 1;
   } else if (res.status === 200) {
     this.messagetype = 2;
   }
})
.catch((err) => {
  this.messagetype = 0;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  // console.log(err );
});
```

Anyone knows a way to catch that console error, not having to remove the custom message in the server result?

Comment: Any luck with finding out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a browser behaviour, that shows the error.
Certain response codes, will in some browsers throw those console messages.

There seems no way to prevent this in a project.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error in heroku in a webpack project with variables environments, i had path of .env file set to local path like c:/project/.env, so the variable of server always return undefined, changing path to relative one fixed the bug:

```
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "development") {
  require("dotenv").config({
    path: ".env.development",
  });
}
```

also check the .env file make sure there is no quotes:

```
SERVER_URI=https://yourApp.com
```

and not this:

```
SERVER_URI="https://yourApp.com"
```

you have to stringify it later in webpackconfig.

this may help someone or give him a hint.